# How do I connect functions between multiple databases?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

When it comes to functions that require database access, I'm trying to figure out how to configure a connection between multiple MySQL databases; one existing in `main.py` and the other in `test.py`. So that when I import functions from main.py to test.py the functions execute against the test database.

This is my first time working with MySQL/Python Connector so I'm not sure how to achieve this.

main.py

```
import mysql.connector

def database_connect(func):
    def wrapper_db_connect():
        with mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=password, database=db)
            return func()
    return wrapper_db_connect

@database_connect
def select_listing(x=None):
    pass

@database_connect
def insert_record():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually simpler than you'd imagine, you'd have to create a global mysql connector variable like so,

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  password="yourpassword"
  database = "databasename"
  )
```

At which point you can use it as a parameter for your functions,

```
#main.py
def exampleFunc(mydb): 
   mycursor = mydb.cursor()
   mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM example")
   return mycursor.fetchall()

 #test.py 
 mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  password="yourpassword"
  database = "test_database"
 )

 val = exampleFunction(mydb)
```